# Unable to understand the output of this

Tags: java, recursion, operators, method-call

I have this code...

```
public class BackHanded {
int state = 0;

BackHanded(int s) {
    state = s;
}

public static void main(String... hi) {
    BackHanded b1 = new BackHanded(1);
    BackHanded b2 = new BackHanded(2);
    System.out.println(b1.go(b1) + " " + b2.go(b2));
}

int go(BackHanded b) {
    if (this.state == 2) {
        b.state = 5;
        go(this);
    }
    return ++this.state;
   }
}
```

Why the statement `return ++this.state;` executed twice here in the second method call?

**EDIT:**
I expected the output to be 2 6. But I got 2 7.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: Because it's a recursion.

Comment: twice create instance

Comment: In recursion where does the return statement return in the first call to go() ?

Comment: When the `state == 2`, you recursively call your method. Hence, you reach twice the return statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method calls itself within itself using recursion.  The recursion does not occur on the first invocation since `state != 2`, however the second invocation satisfies the conditional  `this.state == 2` causing the method to recurse.

```
int go(BackHanded b) {
    if (this.state == 2) {
        b.state = 5;
        go(this);
    }
    return ++this.state;
   }
}
```

The execution of the second invocation of this method `b2.go(b2)` occurs in this manner:

1. The conditional is evaluated and since `state ==2` we fall into the conditional block.
2. Within the conditional block state is assigned to 5.
3. The method then invokes itself (recursion).
4. We start at the conditional once again, this time `state != 2` so we skip the conditional.
5. The method returns `++this.state` or 6 and finishes the invocation of itself.
6. Execution returns to the first invocation, which just finished executing the conditional block, so we head to the return statement `++this.state` or 7.

Comment: Yes, but after executing the statement of go(this), there is no chance of executing return right. only for the second call there is possible but y the return statement is executed twice in this case?>

Comment: You mean return statement called twice on Object b2?

Comment: @MaheshVarma Yes on `b2` my whole answer is in the context of invoking `go` on `b2`.  See my updates that walk through each step of the `b2.go` invocation.

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the recursion. First the `return` statement is called directly from `System.out.println(b1.go(b1) + " " + b2.go(b2));` and then this method itself calls a `go()` method but this time `if (this.state == 2)` is not fulfilled so recursion breaks at this second call.

And this way you can obtain such a callstack:

```
call go(b) //b.state == 2
  call go(b) //b.state == 5
  return ++this.state;
return ++this.state;
```

As it was stated in Arnaud Denoyelle's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since the second `BackHanded` instance `b2` has a value of 2, once it enters the method `go` it checks if the `state` is 2 and since it is, it executes another instance of `go`, now since `state` is no longer 2 it executes `return ++this.state;` after it finishes, it returns to the first call of `go` (since it didnt finish it yet and executes `return ++this.state;` and completes the first `go` method call.

If you want for it to execute only once add a break call inside the if statement.

```
int go(BackHanded b) {
    if (this.state == 2) {
        b.state = 5;
        go(this);
        break;
    }
    return ++this.state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`b1` is initialized with `1`  and you do

```
System.out.println(b1.go(b1) + " " + b2.go(b2));
```

So first look at `b1`.

Value is 1, the `if` statement doesn't trigger, the `++` is executed and the output is `2`.

Now to `b2` which is initialized with 2.

The `if` is triggered because the value is 2, value set to 5 and you call recursivly again. Now the value is 5, the `if` doesn't trigger and the value is increased to 6. The function returns to after the recursive call, at which point the value was already 6 and is again increased to 7. Output is `7`.

Answer (score 0):

```
when the go(b2) is called
  checks(b2.state==2) is true then
    b2.state changes to 5 then
    on coming to return ++(b2) called
  this call will return value 6 now the return statement will be as ++(6) 
    on incrementing 6 it returns 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in seconde case value of state is 2, So `if (this.state == 2)` becomes true then `state  = 5` and next line is `go` that means same method called again.

In this call state value is 5 and return `++this.state` means state = 6, and return to the previous call

```
int go(BackHanded b) {
    if (this.state == 2) {
        b.state = 5;
        go(this); //returned here
    }
    return ++this.state;
   }
}
```

and last return will be `++this.state` means ++6 that means state = 7.